# MySQL: How to query for a column and include information from related columns in the same table?

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

In MySQL, I have a table like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|         Assets        |
+-----------------------+
| Id |   Name  | RootId |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Asset A |    1   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  2 | Asset B |    2   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  3 | Asset C |    3   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  4 | Asset D |    2   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  5 | Asset E |    3   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  6 | Asset F |    3   |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Not the greatest table structure, I know...but I'm stuck with it for now.

I am trying to write a single query that, given an `Id` value, will return a `RootId` and `RootName` ONLY if there are exactly two (2) rows with the same `RootId`. Otherwise those columns should be NULL.

So, using the table above, if given an `Id` of 4 the query should return:

```
+----------------------------------+
|              Assets              |
+----------------------------------+
| Id |   Name  | RootId | RootName |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
|  4 | Asset D |    2   |  AssetB  |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

But if given any other `Id` value, such as 5, it should return:

```
+----------------------------------+
|              Assets              |
+----------------------------------+
| Id |   Name  | RootId | RootName |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
|  5 | Asset E |  null  |   null   |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I think it will require a subquery with a COUNT  and possibly a GROUP BY, but I'm really not sure how to articulate it...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should implement this logic:

```
select id, name,
       (case when cnt = 2 then rootid end) as rootid,
       (case when cnt = 2 then ari.name end) as rootname
from assets a join
     (select rootid, count(*) as cnt
      from assets a
      group by rootid
     ) ri
     on a.rootid = ri.rootid left join
     assets ari
     on a.rootid = ari.id
where id = 4;
```

You can also do this as:

```
select a.id, a.name,
       (case when a.cnt = 2 then a.rootid end) as rootid,
       (case when a.cnt = 2 then ari.name end) as rootname
from (select a.*,
             (select count(*) from assets a2 where a2.rootid = a.rootid) as cnt
      from assets a
      where id = 4
     ) a left join
     assets ari
     on a.rootid = ari.id;
```

Without the full aggregation, this will perform better.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32d97/7) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating them.

Comment: +1. The second should be more efficient for large sets, since it avoids materializing an inline view that gets the count for every possible RootId value. But doesn't there need to be a GROUP BY? The join to `ari` on RootId would return multiple rows, wouldn't it?

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . No, a `group by` is not needed.  Just the correct join.  There should only be at most one match to `ari`.  Thank you.

Comment: @ShaunScovil . . . There was a mistake in the second version, which is now fixed and tested.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Gordon! (Thought I was going crazy for a minute there...) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT a.Id
     , a.Name
     , IF(q.cnt=2,q.RootId,NULL) AS RootId
     , IF(q.cnt=2,q.RootName,NULL) AS RootName
  FROM Assets a
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
              , r.RootId
              , r.RootName
           FROM Assets r
           JOIN Assets s
             ON s.RootId = r.RootId
          WHERE r.Id = 4
          GROUP BY r.RootId, r.RootName
       ) q
    ON q.Id = a.Id
```

If its possible for `RootId` to be NULL, then you'd want to use a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, and include a . If you want to consider a NULL value for `RootId` as matching another NULL value, then replace the equality comparator with the null-safe equality comparison operator,  `<=>`

Adding those two tweaks gives a more robust solution:

```
SELECT a.Id
     , a.Name
     , IF(q.cnt=2,q.RootId,NULL) AS RootId
     , IF(q.cnt=2,q.RootName,NULL) AS RootName
  FROM Assets a
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
              , r.RootId
              , r.RootName
           FROM Assets r
           LEFT                                -- lef outer join
           JOIN Assets s
             ON s.RootId <=> r.RootId          -- nullsafe equality
          WHERE r.Id = 4
          GROUP BY r.RootId, r.RootName
       ) q
    ON q.Id = a.Id
```